# Expected end of line but found “"”. is showing up on apple script editor

Tags: macos, applescript, editor

```
tell application "Finder" to say "this is a test"
tell aplication"finder"  
    activate
    repeat 5 times
        make new Finder window
    end repeat
end tell
```

I am just learning different coding and know quite a bit about html, css, and javascript. I am completely new to apple script editor.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're new to applescript I'll give you a basic tip to learn. Only tell an application to do something that it knows how to do. Each application knows how to do specific things and applescript knows how to do things by itself too.

I tell you this because the "say" command is an applescript command, not a Finder command. So there's no reason to tell the Finder to say anything. As you get more complex in your scripts you will find errors if you tell the wrong application to do something. As such you can run the say command by itself. Try this and it will work by itself...

```
say "this is a test"
```

The easiest way to know what each application understands is to look in the dictionaries. In Script Editor, under the file menu choose "open dictionary". You can choose any application but for this example open the Finder dictionary. You can search through it to find what the Finder knows how to do. You'll notice it doesn't have the "say" command thus you know not to tell the Finder to use the say command. You can type "say" into the search field and you'll see it doesn't return any results.

If you open the dictionary for "StandardAdditions" you'll find say in there. That's additional things applescript knows by itself.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you soo much   ive looked everywhere for an answer and none seened to be specific to my question

Answer (score -2):

The part `tell aplication"finder"` has two typos and is missing a space. It should be `tell application "Finder"`

The whole think should look like this which builds for me.

```
tell application "Finder" to say "this is a test"
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    repeat 5 times
        make new Finder window
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: If you're going to down vote this answer, please add a comment saying why. As far as I can tell, this answers the question that was asked.